# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "BatchID": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

Why am i getting the error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "BatchID": syntax error"?

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderBatch(
                    OrderBatchID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    Quantity INTEGER,
                    OrderID INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES OrderTable(OrderID),
                    BatchID INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (BatchID) REFERENCES Batch(BatchID)
                    )''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definitions of the foreign keys at the end of the statement.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderBatch(
                    OrderBatchID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    Quantity INTEGER,
                    OrderID INTEGER,
                    BatchID INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES OrderTable(OrderID),
                    FOREIGN KEY (BatchID) REFERENCES Batch(BatchID)
                    )
```